# ActionScript 3: get the first character from the first element of an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am learning AS3 (coming from a PHP background) and I have hit a wall.

Basically I have this code:

```
var activeNotesNames:Array;
activeNotesNames = new Array;

activeNotesNames.push("ABC");
```

and doing a

```
trace(activeNotesNames[0])
```

gives me "ABC" but if I just want the first character (in this case that would be "A") how do I get that?

I tried `trace(activeNotesNames[0][0]` but that gives me an error.

Comment: The problem with `[0][0]` is that the String "ABC" is not an array. As Pan pointed out, you need to use a method of the String class to access individual characters. That syntax would work if instead of having a String you had another array in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activeNotesNames[0].charAt(0);
```

Or you can try substr

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me which is an easy place to look up methods like this? Compared to php.net finding this stuff for AS3 is quite hard... but I think I am looking in the wrong places. (I have to wait 9 mins to accept your answer)

Comment: You can find the api in adobe livedoc, it helps a lot when you are not familiar with the api.                               http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html